# Levantar este requerimiento

Tags: uml

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola tenia estos levantamientos de requerimiento pero la verdad no me queda muy claro cual debe ir al documento de requisitos. Al diagrama de caso de uso deberia ir Paciente -> presiona boton. Pero no me queda claro cual de los 3 requerimientos levantar.

Comment: De entrada ninguno; el caso es que el paciente pueda llamar al doctor, el cómo, ya sea mediante un botón, o un chasquido de dedos, o un sensor infrarrojo, etc. es detalle del modelo de diseño. En los requerimientos quieres sabes ¿qué? ¿por qué? ¿para qué?, el ¿cómo? no lo debe determinar el usuario.

Comment: Entonces el botón no iría, ahora la notificación si.